# What are these two types of methods termed?

Tags: c#, oop, methods

Some methods will perform an operation on an object's property (can't think of an example), but some methods will not actually affect an object's property but just return a value (DateTime.Add() for example).

I know it's a simple question but I don't know how to refer to the two types of methods.

Comment: I really think some sample code would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Property Access Methods** and **Derived Property Methods** are what I've used in the past to differentiate.

For example a property access method may well do the following for an imaginary property that isn't stored as a DateTime.

```
DateTime GetOrderDateTime()
{
    return OrderDate.ConvertToDateTime();
}
```

a derived property method would be:

```
DateTime GetNextOrderDate()
{
    return GetOrderDate.AddOneMonth(...);
}
```

I'm deliberately avoiding the discussion about what should be properties and what should be methods on the understanding that this is well defined in the context posted by the OP.

Modifying properties within these methods, as Adam says is a good way to introduce side effects - best to stick with good names (e.g. ModifyTotal) and conventions that Get methods and property gets should never (normally) modify properties.

Comment: I've seen a few of your posts since I joined this forum and you're always explaining things in a way that's easy to understand, straight to the point, thanks mate.

Answer (score 4):

Can't think of the first, but the second could possibly be termed **side-effect free**, as in, [it doesn't mutate state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).  It isn't so much how you'd refer to it, more a description of its behaviour.

You tend to hear "side-effect" used in concurrent languages, Axum had this concept baked in.

For example, this method is side-effect free:

```
public string GetName()
{
    return "Adam";
}
```

Whereas this method isn't:

```
public int GetTotal(int optionalValue = 0)
{
    _total += optionalValue;
    return _total;
}
```

It may mutate state (in this case `_total`) as part of the method call.  The next time you call it, `_total` may or may not be the same as last time as a result of the method call itself.

Unless you are thinking of property setters...

```
public string Name 
{
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

...I don't think there is any common term for describing methods.  Most methods in objects will use internal state in some way - read or write.

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply said

- Instance Method
- Static Method

Comment: +1 This is most likely what is being asked, if only there was some sample code from the OP :-)